# how to encoding json request to post to REST server

Tags: json

I need to call the API method "newPhoto" REST web service to post new photo to a specific client.

The "newPhoto" method is defined as below:

```
￼￼￼￼method=newPhoto
```

￼Request example in JSON:

```
￼￼￼￼{"1":{"method":"newPhoto","arguments":["1192685","\/9j\/4A...” ,"front view"]}}
```

￼
￼￼￼￼Response example in JSON:￼

```
{"1":{"status":"success","result":28961285}}
```

---

I have two question:

1. how should I encode the `data` in the following:

   `ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, data);`

   Do I need to encode "data" to call the `newPhoto` method? How?
2. If I have a data_class contains all photo data, how can I pass the `data_class` to `ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, data);`?

I am not sure if my question is clear, because I am confused about how to pass .